# Windows Boot Manager Screen comes up even though I have 1 OS

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootmgr, boot-manager

One day, I turned on my computer as I usually would. No other operating systems on it except for Windows 7. (Although I'm thinking about dual booting it with Linux.) However, then and almost every time I boot it up, bootmgr.exe comes up and prompts me to select "Windows 7" or "Windows Diagnostic Tools". Everything seems to be fine with my computer, however, around this time my antivirus both found and deleted a virus.

If I select "Windows 7", it boots up just as normal. I can't figure out what happened to it, but it started happening around the time of a power outage.

**Specs**

- Windows 7 Home Premium - 64 bit
- Intel Pentium E6700 Dual Core CPU @ 3.20GHz
- Dell 018D1Y, version A00, revision A3 motherboard (CPU 1)
- 931GB Hitachi HDS721010CLA332 (SATA)
- 6.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 531MHz RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view complete contents of BCD using [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net).

{bootmgr} object in BCD holds all relevant boot menu settings(elements).

The main element for boot menu is "DisplayOrder" - a list of boot entries(loader ID's).

If there is only one boot entry in "DisplayOrder" then there will be no boot menu  displayed and booting will continue using settings for the single boot entry (these settings are elements of the OS loader object like OS folder, OS loader path and so on).

If there are two or more boot menu entries boot menu is displayed as long as specified in "timeout" element (number means seconds).

There is also the "default" element which specifies the default boot entry to be chosen after "timeout" expires.

This is almost everything about boot menu and BCD without going into details ;)

Comment: I believe if you change the timeout to 0, this boot menu will be bypassed which should solve the OP's problem as well

Comment: Interesting is also what will happen if you delete "DisplayOrder". Will it boot directly "default"? I wish I had more time to play ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your system boot option got changed. You can review them at Control Panel - System - Advanced System Settings (System Properties) - Startup and Recovery Settings.

FYI there is no "bootmgr.exe", the filename is just "bootmgr".

Comment: Can you provide specifics on how the author removes the redundant/invalid boot option?

Comment: I'm supposed to uncheck [this](http://imgur.com/2VWyh1K) setting, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Run "msconfig" then choose "Boot", check whether there are multiple entries here. Configure Windows 7 as the default boot system, delete the entry you didn't want to have.